# Bootstrap-datepicker and multidate values in input field

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I use Bootstrap-datepicker with embedded and multidate options.
I would like that chosen dates appear in the input field. How to do this?

I try this code but only one date appear :

```
$('#date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e){
$('#date_input').val(e.format('mm/dd/yyyy'));
});
```

With this other solution, the date format is not convenient for me :

```
$('#date').datepicker().on('changeDate',function(){
var value=$("#date").datepicker("getDates");
$('#date_input').val(value);    
});
```

I also love the format is as follows: `dd/mm/yyyy`

For instance : `06/07/2014`, `07/07/2014`, `10/07/2014`

Can you help me please?
In advance thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: value has a list of UTC date objects. Enumerate that and apply the date format to each object in the list.

Comment: Did you solve this yet? I can't figure out how to easily do this

Answer (score 0):

```
var picker = $('#picker').datepicker();

console.log( picker.datepicker('getFormattedDate') );
```